# instafeed not even showing up

Tags: javascript, html, instagram

I followed the exact procedure at instafeedjs.com and put this code before  :

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="instafeed.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      var feed = new Instafeed({
          get: 'tagged',
          tagName: 'Thowed',
          clientId: '2b053f9f5bae49ba8add26a5ddb8e933'
      });
      feed.run();
  </script>
  <div id="instafeed"></div>
```

I really can't see where the error is. instafeed.min.js is in the root folder... What could be the other issue please?

Comment: You have invalid `clientId`, make sure you have registered one and again follow the instruction from their website

Comment: I made a second Client and followed the instructions verbatim. I keep trying both client ids, but still nothing.

Comment: Did you check what's in console ? It should show why it is not working.

Comment: How can I bring the console?