# instafeed not even showing up - how to debug?

Tags: javascript, html, instagram

I followed the exact procedure at instafeedjs.com and put this code before :

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="instafeed.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      var feed = new Instafeed({
          get: 'tagged',
          tagName: 'Thowed',
          clientId: '2b053f9f5bae49ba8add26a5ddb8e933'
      });
      feed.run();
  </script>
  <div id="instafeed"></div>
```

I really can't see where the error is. instafeed.min.js is in the root folder... What could be the other issue please? What is the best approach to debug? I tried to add a document.write statement inside the beginning of the javascript, but nothing was printed in the console.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [instafeed not even showing up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285428/instafeed-not-even-showing-up)

Comment: Please do not deliberately duplicate your questions.